# In need of a color aerial photography or LIDAR

Tags: images

I am seeking a few color aerial photography that are the most recently that I need to cover this area of interest.

It has to be overlapped in 60/40 percent  so I can perform them in an Agisoft Metashape.

Location is in Central Colorado
It is in the border between Leadville/Chaffee counties.

Point of interest is Twin Lakes river area. It is just to the west all the way to the east leading to the Lake.

Let me know if you are able to see the Area of Interest in Google Earth.

In order to see it,

Go to the Menu at the top left corner, then
Hit the projects, then
It should say Survey Area.

Google Earth :

https://earth.google.com/web/search/Twin+Lakes,+CO/@39.13113129,-106.42151985,3599.28893251a,44275.95222716d,35y,0h,0t,0r/data=CigiJgokCf8jXbmA3zRAEfwjXbmA3zTAGYU_JarUuihAIfMfULmClVbA

ArcGIS Online : https://arcg.is/1jiHD50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I found one that allowed me to fill it out from the state of Colorado Hazard Mapping Department

https://coloradohazardmapping.com/

P.S. For those that want the LIDAR from on that site, I do want to caution you that the data is very large to download even if you want to submit them your area of interest shapefile..